# Stochastic differential equation solution suggestion

Tags: stochastic-calculus

Any suggestion on solving the stochastic differential equation

\begin{align}
dW(t) = d\widetilde{W}(t) + \left(\frac{\kappa - W(t)}{\tau-t} - \frac{1}{\kappa - W(t)}\right)dt 
\end{align}

where $\kappa,\tau\in\mathbb{R}$ are known and $\widetilde{W}(t)$ is a standard Brownian motion and $W(t)$ a Gaussian process ?

I tried looking this equation as a bridge, but it is not a bridge.